# Getting the NetCfgInstanceId of a NIC

Tags: go, registry

If you know the name of a network card, how can you get its instance ID?
eg: `WLAN 2 {74892867-F98B-454B-904F-88912DDE4B9F}`.
I don't want to use the command line; it's better to work with the registry. What should be the policy that matches the network card in the registry `(HKLM/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/Class/{4d36e972-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318})`?

Language: Go 1.11
Platform: Windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get All NetCfgInstanceId on Your Windows.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"
)

const ADAPTER_KEY = `SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E972-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`

func main() {
    k, err := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, ADAPTER_KEY, registry.ENUMERATE_SUB_KEYS|registry.QUERY_VALUE)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer k.Close()

    keyNames, err := k.ReadSubKeyNames(-1)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    for _, keyName := range keyNames {
        n, _ := matchKey(k, keyName)
        if n != "" {
            fmt.Println(n)
        }
    }
}

func matchKey(zones registry.Key, keyName string) (string, error) {
    k, err := registry.OpenKey(zones, keyName, registry.READ)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer k.Close()

    netCfgInstanceId, _, err := k.GetStringValue("NetCfgInstanceId")
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    return netCfgInstanceId, nil
}
```